# What statistical test would be best for determining if one group is directly correlated to another?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, dependent-variable

I have to determine if temperature values are the direct cause of three groups, low, medium, and high. I would assign each of these groups a number, low would be 1, medium 2, and high 3, so the data would look something like this:

| temperature | mode |
| --- | --- |
| 27 | 3 |
| 93 | 2 |
| 100 | 1 |

What statistical test can I conduct to determine if the temperature has a direct affect on the mode?

Comment: You can test the Spearman correlation between the two. Avoid regular Pearson correlation with your ordinal “mode” variable. // You mention about wanting to show that temperature “causes” mode. A correlation study is inadequate for that purpose. Causal inference is its own entire field.